# What structure does a news article site use?

Tags: html, web, structure

I've been slowly coding my own website for a few weeks now and I'd like to feature my own article section but have no idea how to structure it. I looked at various websites that use similar systems to what I would like to use but some have 100's of articles. Not all of them use their own HTML page, for sure.

Is there a faster way around this?

For example if i click a thumbnail article and it takes me to the full page, is that always a whole separate html page? So within your directory you are left with hundreds of html files.

Couple of the sites I've been taking inspiration from:

- http://cloud9.gg
- http://clgaming.net

Comment: You would be more inspired of the situations of the 100-article websites if php or other server-side languages are supported

Comment: no you need to implement a CMS (content management system) with a use of a database you only code the surrounding layout and pull the article content from database records I would advise trying to look into WordPress to start with.

Comment: Is there ways i can use this system with my site I've built already?

Comment: you will be able to reuse some html code with it